# Virtual hosting with a LAMP server and Ubuntu 12.04 with Filezilla

Tags: 12.04, apache2, lamp, filezilla

I have 2 domains I wish to host on 1 server.

I would like to know how I can add/remove/change my web sites only with Filezilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to login as `root` in Filezilla to access the configuration files. With Apache, they will be located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. You will also be required to symlink or `cp` them to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` for them to be activated.

Base two new files off of `default`, change the domain and location, remove the `default_server` and upload them.

They should look something like this:

```
<VirtalHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html_public

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/html_public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow, deny
        allow form all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/example/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/www/example/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```